# Why are the X11 window identifiers so large (long unsigned) integers?

Tags: x11

I would imagine that the window IDs would simply be the count of windows for a specific display but why are they in practise so large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid having to synchronize between clients to allocate new ids, each X11 client is simply given a large range of resource ids for their use, and ids come out of that set, regardless of what other clients have used in their sets.

Furthermore resource identifiers are used for objects other than toplevel windows, so if you only list window identifiers, you'll see many holes that are actually occupied by other objects.